# iAd for Landscape only application throwing error

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation, iad

Hi I have my landscape only app. I am adding iAd to it and i click on test add my app crashes with this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

In my app delegate i have

```
_bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
```

and in my VC i am again setting

```
[_bannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
```

To keep my app Landspace only I have

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: Probably won't solve it but it'll make your app less annoying; use `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` otherwise 1 of the 2 landscape orientations are ignored.

Comment: sir I want my app to run only in one orientation, but is that a reason my app is crashing when i am click on ad?

Comment: The error reported claims that your application is attempting to run in an invalid orientation. Did you happen to allow the left orientation in your Info.plist?

Comment: no it is working fine on 5.1 OS and simulator. Error is only coming on iOS 6.0

Comment: @SamWoodbury Read the changes to shouldAutoRotate in the iOS 6.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by updating my code with latest SDK changes